# Access Webpack Dev Server on another LAN PC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server, webpack-dev-server

I created an app with create-react-app and the *webpack-dev-server* uses the react-scripts to load up the *dev-server*. The problem is i cannot access the *dev server* via other LAN PC. Any idea how to solve this? I also have a *.env* file where i change the default HOST name to domain.com.

I want to access the *dev-server* via my iPad for example. Earlier i just typed in the IP of the PC and the port and it worked.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost
just simply by adding

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
};
```

or directly via cli

```
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: After to configure this, you have to access via browser from the **other LAN device** to the **Developing Machine** IP address:port. On linux a possible way could be with the command: `ip address`, and look for a **192.168.xxx.xxx** class address.

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem, i resolve with this:
Example IP: 192.168.0.35
'webpack.dev.config.js'

```
module.exports {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://192.168.0.35:3001/'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    host: '192.168.0.35'
  }
}
```

Comment: After trying many solutions this worked, but I had to change my index.js file. The script tag should look at "http://192.168.0.13:9000/bundle.js" instead of "localhost:900" which is the default